# easynetQ delayed respond/request resulting in timeout

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

I've run into a problem with using the request/respond pattern of EasyNetQ while using it on our server (Windows Server 2008). Not able to reproduce it locally at the moment.

The setup is we have 2 windows services (running as console applications for testing) which are connected through the request/respond pattern in EasyNetQ. This has been working as expected until recently on the server where the request side does not "consume" the responses until after the request timeouts.

I have included 2 links to pastebin which contain the console logging of EasyNetQ which will hopefully make my problem a bit more clear.

[RequestSide](http://pastebin.com/JYWi9iPu)

[RespondSide](http://pastebin.com/Ei2mRDCD)

Besides that, my request code looks like this:

```
var request = new foobar(); 
var response = _bus.Request<foobar, foobar2>(request);
```

and on the respond side:

```
var response = new response();
_bus.Respond<foobar, foobar2>(request =>
       {                    
            try
            {
                ....
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ....
                return response;
            }
        });
```

As I've said, the request side sends the request as expected and the respond side consumes/catches it. This works as it should, but when the respond side is done processing and responds (which it does, the messages can be seen in the RabbitMQ management thingy) the request doesn't consume/catch the response until after the request has timed out (default timeout is 10s, tried setting to 60s aswell, makes no difference). This is also evident in the logs linked above as you'll see on the RequestSide, with the 5 or so messages received from the response queue which previously timed out.

I've tried using RespondAsync in case the processing was taking too long and messing something up, didn't help. Tried using both RespondAsync & RequestAsync, just messed everything up even more (I was probably doing something wrong with the request :)).

I might be missing something, but I'm not sure what to try from here.

EDIT: Noticed I messed something up. As well as added more context below:

The IBus used for the request/response is created and injected with Ninject:

```
class FooModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        { 
            Bind<IBus>().ToMethod(ctx => RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost", x => x.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(_ => logger))).InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
```

And it's all tied together by the service being constructed using Topshelf with Ninject like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.UseNinject(new FooModule());
                x.Service<FooService>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsingNinject();
                    s.WhenStarted((service, control) => service.Start(control));
                    s.WhenStopped((service, control) => service.Stop(control));
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            });
        }
```

The Topshelf setup has all been tested pretty thoroughly and it works as intended, and should not really be relevant for the request/respond problem, but I thought I would provide a bit more context.

Comment: I'm having a problem similar to this, and it *just* started happening yesterday.  One note - if we issue the Request from the same process that is handling the Response - it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, my problem was i set the timeout only in the response but not in the request side, after i set the timeoute in both side it worked fine 
my connection for eg.
host=hostname;timeout=120;virtualHost=myhost;username=myusername;passw
ord=mypassword